# specifying a custom font in css (otf) - How to specify bold/italic/etc when provided multiple otf files?

Tags: css, font-face

I'm a little unclear on how to use @font-face in my current situation.  The client provided me with several font files such as FontName-Black.otf, FontName-BlackItalic.otf, FontName-Bold.otf, FontName-BoldItalic.otf, etc.

I understand that typically I would do the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: FontName;
    src("path/FontName.otf") format("opentype")
}
```

Do I have to specify each one of the font names provided?  How does css know which font is the default and which font to apply to bold (when the `<strong>` tag is used) or italic (when the `<em>` tag is used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use multiple @font-face 's, like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontName";
  src: url("FontName-Black.otf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "FontName";
  src: url("FontName-BlackItalic.otf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "FontName";
  src: url("FontName-Bold.otf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Then to specify just use this:

```
body { font-family:"FontName", //you can add the exact fonts you want to use here }

h1 { font-weight:bold; }

p { font-style:italic; }

strong p{
  font-weight:bold;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

Comment: No problem! ;))